# Getting ENOTSUP error on nodejs 0.12.6 app running in Azure Websites

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I recently upgraded by version of nodejs on my windows azure web application from 0.12.0 to 0.12.6. Since then, whenever I relaunch my app on visual studio online editor, the console reports a significant errors like these ones:

```
glob error { [Error: ENOTSUP, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\views\partials\recommendationModal.handlebars']
  errno: -4049,
  code: 'ENOTSUP',
  path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\views\\partials\\recommendationModal.handlebars' }
glob error { [Error: ENOTSUP, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\views\partials\register.handlebars']
  errno: -4049,
  code: 'ENOTSUP',
  path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\views\\partials\\register.handlebars' }
glob error { [Error: ENOTSUP, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\views\partials\search.handlebars']
  errno: -4049,
  code: 'ENOTSUP',
  path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\views\\partials\\search.handlebars' }
glob error { [Error: ENOTSUP, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\views\partials\spinningWheel.handlebars']
  errno: -4049,
  code: 'ENOTSUP',
  path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\views\\partials\\spinningWheel.handlebars' }
glob error { [Error: ENOTSUP, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\views\partials\stylesFilterButtons.handlebars']
  errno: -4049,
  code: 'ENOTSUP',
  path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\views\\partials\\stylesFilterButtons.handlebars' }
```

All of the files in the error descriptions are handlebars partials.

I run the same app on my local development environment (linux with nodejs 0.12.6) and these errors never show up.

At first glance, it looks like there is something broken on azure websites when running your app on 0.12.6, but I'd like to post this situation here in SO to see if other people have faced the same issue and how they managed to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very much looks like [this bug](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/issues/205). Sounds like you may have glob 5.0.13 or earlier installed. Try 5.0.14 and it will hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: Seems like this is the case. This error was being thrown by the module express-handlebars. In my app, it was installed with version 1.x. I upgraded the module to version 2.0.1 (which include the version of glob you mention above), and the problem disappeared. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue with Azure. Mine happened to be glob as one comment stated.

express-handlebars has fixed this issue if you update to 3.0.0